# Mvc Bundling, Cache with Content or Cache with file name?

Tags: model-view-controller, caching, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I'm deciding to remove all versions from static content that has been referenced in my Mvc Web Application. but I need caching.

I want to know does the browser cache contents by file name or by content ?
for example if I Bundle a Jquery version 1.6 without version information (i.e jquery.js), and then I put version 1.8 of jquery with the previous file name (jquery.js). what will happen ? does the browser get the new file or not ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bundling generates the cache code in the bundle url(the ?v=12345) via the actual contents of the file, so you will get a different bundle url that the browser will cache each time you change the actual contents of the bundle.